# What percentage of closed questions that get submitted for review are eventually re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, statistics, reopened-questions

Just curious, what percentage of questions that get submitted (and/or re-submitted) for review by the post owner get eventually reopened after the "significant edit" option was added to the Stack Exchange sites?

I've been submitting review requests for a lot of my questions that don't get re-opened. (This is not a complaint, I just want the statistics for this).

I want the numbers for Stack Overflow, and the whole network in general (combined as one). I specifically want numbers for the period *after* [the significant changes announced in 2021-08](/q/369013)

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [What percentage of closed questions were reopened after an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333987/348196) (this was before the "significant edit" option was a thing).

Comment: Per request, part of this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1647/discussion-on-question-by-enderman-how-many-percent-of-questions-that-get-submit).

Comment: Anecdotally, I've had quite a bit of success using the checkbox, but that's been on a medium sized site that only requires two other people to vote to reopen, plus I know the site inside and out. It may be hard to draw any meaningful conclusions about each site from the data.

Comment: Probably of interest are the "year in moderation" posts, which are posted to each Meta site once a year. For SO, the most recent is "[2021: a year in moderation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415250/3773011)". They contain line items for "Questions closed", "Tasks reviewed: Reopen Vote queue", and "Questions reopened", which will at least *hint* at the numbers you're looking for, but won't be exact and *will be inaccurate* compared to current actual, because substantial changes were made substantially into the year and the differences to 2020 indicate those changes made a dramatic difference.

Comment: IIRC, there is, somewhere, a post from someone on staff with numbers close to what you're interested in, at least for SO (maybe network wide?), with reopen queue % performance, including re-closing and deletions, but I don't have a link for it and might be misremembering. It was *probably* on Meta Stack Overflow, but my memory of it is vague at this point.

Comment: Related: [the post on cross-site queries in data explorer](/q/83570/997587). See also the `PostHistory` table in [the SEDE schema docs](/q/2677/997587)